# Posting data to Silex app ( jwt authentication using cnam/security-jwt-service-provider )

Tags: web-services, symfony, silex, jwt, postman

I am creating web service using silex micro framework. This is first time i am using it and I dont have prior knowledge on symfony. I could be able to understand how silex works and how to write controller providers , service providers etc ..

I couldnt work out authentication for my webservice.
I want to use JWT authentication and I found this **cnam/security-jwt-service-provider** extending **firebase/php-jwt**.

I set it up right and I get this output when I access protected resource

```
{"message":"A Token was not found in the TokenStorage."}
```

which is correct.

**Question:** I want to post the username , password to application and get token back. ( username=admin , password=foo )
I am using postman chrome extension ( also used Advanced rest client ) to post values to url ( http://silex.dev/api/login)

Post data I am sending

Key=> username Value=> admin
Key=> password Value=> foo

I also tried

Key=> _username Value=> admin
Key=> _password Value=> foo

Aldo tried key vaule pairs in basic auth headers.

response I get id

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error": "Invalid credentials"
}
```

When I debug the Application I see no post data at all.
    $vars = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
I get null $var.

PS: I know I will get a valid token back if I get these values posted correctly because I edited values from empty to correct values in breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I should send data in json format and should set content-type appication/json

eg:

```
{
  "_username":"admin",
  "_password":"foo"
}
```

and response will something be like

```
{
  success: true
  token: "eyJ0eXAiOisKV1diLCJfbGgiOhJIjzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJleHAiOjE0Mzk5MDUxMjh9.DMdXAv2Ay16iI1UQbHZABLCU_gsD_j9-gEU2M2L2MFQ"
```

}